# title tag html editing

Tags: tags, title

hey everyone am trying to add my title tag but every time i try to put it in the format of  Company name| Primary keyword and Secondary keyword i get parsing error which is ''Error parsing XML, line 516, column 29: Element type "ShareFreeTemplates" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" and here is my html code

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>

<!--::::::::::: Block2: Output Index Title,keywords,decription and Post Title,description -->
<!-- Post/Archive Page -->
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;index&quot;'>
   <title><data:blog.pageName/></title>

<!-- Index Page -->   
<b:else/>
  <title><ShareFreeTemplates|Free After Effects Templates And-Tutorials /></title>
   <meta content='after effects free templates, templates, after effects project files, free download' name='keywords'/>

</b:if>
```

if somebody can edit that title tag to give me no errors i want it like that ''Free After Effects Templates and Project Files| ShareFreeTemplates'' and thx in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the title tag works in standard HTML coding.

`<title> insert words here </title>` are the tags used. and then you insert the words in between the two tags like so

```
<title>ShareFreeTemplates|Free After Effects Templates And-Tutorials </title>
```

you dont need to encapsulate your title in another pair of tags.

```
  <title><ShareFreeTemplates|Free After Effects Templates And-Tutorials /></title>
         ^                                                              ^^
        //remove the characters where the arrows are pointing at
```

Comment: when i removed them i got error 400 and the writing color capsulated was green now it turned black

Comment: @user3161992 I believe your error lies else where buddy. As for title tags, this is exactly how they work. Also check line 516 and the lines before it :) the error must lay there

Comment: oh the problem was with the blogger preview :D it gave me error 400 even with the fresh template .. i checked and it's changed ... thx alot bro